# C# Check if ConsoleKeyInfo.KeyChar is a number

Tags: c#, input

```
ConsoleKeyInfo CKI = Console.ReadKey(true);
```

CKI.KeyChar is the unicode equivalent of the character input
So if I'd press '1' in the console prompt CKI.KeyChar would be 49, not the value '1'.

How do I get the value '1'?

I know its a devious way of getting the input, but its the way my teacher wants it so I cant do it otherwise.

Edit: I need the value that the user gave, because I'm going to have to check if its less than 9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`.KeyChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar.aspx) property and compare with [`Char.IsNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isnumber.aspx).

To get the numeric equivalent, you can use [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) or [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx):

```
Int32 number;
if (Int32.TryParse(cki.KeyChar.ToString(), out number))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}, Less than 9?: {1}", number, number < 9);
}
```

---

#### Test Application:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press CTRL+C to exit, otherwise press any key.");
    ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
    do
    {
        cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (!Char.IsNumber(cki.KeyChar))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Non-numeric input");
        }
        else
        {
            Int32 number;
            if (Int32.TryParse(cki.KeyChar.ToString(), out number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number received: {0}; <9? {1}", number, number < 9);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse input");
            }
        }
    }
    while (cki.KeyChar != 27);
}
}
```

Comment: .TryParse seems safer than .Parse for me since the user can insert characters, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
char.IsDigit(CKI.KeyChar);
```

If you need to convert it into a number, use this:

```
int myNumber = int.Parse(CKI.KeyChar.ToString())
```

To check if its less than 9, then you do this:

```
if (myNumber < 9)
{
     // Its less than 9. Do Something
} else {
     // Its not less than 9. Do something else
}
```

Comment: It doesn't, it had to be converted to string before I could parse it.

Comment: I Just fixed the code to convert the char to a string before parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the easy way (see below), or you can use the enum `ConsoleKey` to identify which key was pressed — `ConsoleKey.D[0-9]` are the normal decimal digit keys, and `ConsoleKey.NumPad[0-9]` the numeric key pad keys. Might want to check what modifiers were pressed using the enum `ConsoleModifiers`. That enum has the `Flags` attribute on it, so the values can be combined with bitwise OR. For instance, if the property `ConsoleKeyInfo.Modifiers` is `ConsoleModifiers.Control|ConsoleModifiers.Alt`, then the user pressed the [CTL] and [ALT] keys along with whatever other key was pressed.

```
public static void Main( string[] args )
{

  Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true ;

  Console.Write("? ") ;
  while ( true )
  {
    ConsoleKeyInfo keystroke = Console.ReadKey() ;
    Console.WriteLine();

    if ( keystroke.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control && keystroke.Key == ConsoleKey.C ) break ;

    int decimalDigit = ((int)keystroke.KeyChar) - ((int)'0') ;
    if ( decimalDigit >= 0 && decimalDigit <= 9 )
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Decimal Digit {0}", decimalDigit ) ;
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine( "Not a decimal digit!" ) ;
    }
    Console.Write("? ") ;
  }

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

49 is just an ascii code, so you can do `char c = (char) 49` and get the actual character.

Comment: CKI.KeyChar is already a character so why would I cast it? It holds 49 if I debug or echo it.